# Время обновления DNS

Tags: dns, домен

Как быстро обновляется dns? Прикрепил домен к хостингу, но зайти не могу. Что поделать - ума не приложу. Сколько нужно примерно ждать?

Comment: Чистка кеша своего ПК точно скажет, обновились или нет днс и кеш провайдера. Если да, сайт откроется нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Корневые сервера зоны RU обновляются 4 раза в сутки: в 2, 10, 14, 19 часов(MSK)

COM не более получаса. Для различных доменных зон отличается.

Однако все ещё зависит от того как часто обновляется DNS у вашего провайдера

Comment: Период, на кторый должна кешироваться запись DNS определяется TTL этой записи и настройками DNS серверов (и того, на котором лежит зона и кеширующих). Обычно понижение TTL позволяет обновлять зону быстрее, но все администраторы задают минимальный порог, ниже которого частота обновления увеличиваться не будет

Answer (score 3):

от 15 минут до недели. Множество факторов (ваш кеш, кеш провайдера, промежуточных узлов)

Можете попробовать так

1. пуск - выполнить - cmd
2. ipconfig /flushdns (+enter)

если не поможет,

1. пуск - выполнить - cmd
2. %windir%/system32/drivers/etc/ (именно так)
3. там будет файл hosts
4. открываете в блокноте и добавляете в конец строку
5. a.b.c.d вашдомен.ru (где a.b.c.d - ip вашего сайта)

через недельку не забудьте убрать эту строку )

Answer (score 1):

от 15 минут до 72х часов :)